# vertical alignment of parbox one below the other

Tags: parbox

I want to align all the parboxes vertically so that the left corners are are equally offset from the dates which are in the left side

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}


\begin{document}
                \begin{center}{\large \textbf{HANDING / TAKING OVER}}\end{center}
            \begin{description}         

\item AON for CHT
\subitem 11 Nov 2019--\parbox{\textwidth}{Preetha check progress with IFA}
\subitem 12 Nov 2019--\parbox{\textwidth}{Preetha to liaise with IFA}
\subitem 14 Nov 2019--\parbox{\textwidth}{ IFA has asked to come on next Wednesday}

\item Video Conferencing with ADGQA
\subitem 13 Nov 2019--\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{ pts for discussion}
\subsubitem Padmavathy for Digital DGQA--\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{She will be available for guidance but Kannan should take over \\--if required he can got to Bangalore}
\subsubitem Component Level Repair CLR--\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{  83 items\\{-- }to be decided by CQAL, Bangalore\\Action by Debnath}
\subsubitem FR 56j--\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{  List upto Jun 2020 to be sent \\{--}list again faxed on 14 Nov 2019\\ Vishwanath case--decision already conveyed as told by Col Vibhor}
\subsubitem Cover assembly BMP--\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{  2017 pending?\\ FFT?\\ Delay to be pinpointed \\Delay in G1 Form? \\Action by Kambli}
\subsubitem Digital DGQA--\parbox{\textwidth}{  Action by  --Kannan}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Re @Johannes_B:not compiling
Just ran it and it compiles--throwing up the image below from screen capture

[image]

And the code says `No Error No Warnings`see below

[image]

Comment: Your example does not compile and throws several overful hbox warnings otherwise.

Comment: @Johannes_B please see the EDIT above in main question--compiles correctly

Comment: First, the remaining space in a list environment is \linewidth, not \textwidth.  Anyway, what you need is to use a common width (\makebox) for the dates.

Comment: request one example--remaining I will take on

Comment: in such cases is it better to go for `tabularx` or `minipage` or some custom `list`--anything I can refer/read

Comment: Oops, \subitem and \sussubitem do not set \linewidth.

Comment: `\subitem`and `\subsubitem` are specific commands for use in the `theindex` environment. They're not supported elsewhere and their action outside of a `theindex` environment should be considered random.

Comment: You might also look at the outlintes package.  It doesn't solve this problem, but it makes this type of document easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty of aligning the `--` dividers.  I got the 20pt and 30pt from the definitions of `\subitem` and `\subsubitem` in article.cls.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% use showframe for debugging only
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\newlength{\datewidth}
\settowidth{\datewidth}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}% overkill
  11 Nov 2019-- \\
  12 Nov 2019-- \\
  14 Nov 2019-- \\
  13 Nov 2019--
\end{tabular}}
%\settowidth{\datewidth}{22 Nov 2019--}% IIRC 2 is the widest digit

\newcommand{\myitem}[2]% #1 = date, #2 = text
  {\subitem \makebox[\datewidth][r]{#1}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\datewidth-20pt}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mysubitem}[2]% #1 = heding, #2 = text
  {\sbox0{#1}\subsubitem \usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0-30pt}{#2}}

\begin{document}
                \begin{center}{\large \textbf{HANDING / TAKING OVER}}\end{center}
            \begin{description}         

\item AON for CHT
\myitem{11 Nov 2019--}{Preetha check progress with IFA}
\myitem{12 Nov 2019--}{Preetha to liaise with IFA}
\myitem{14 Nov 2019--}{ IFA has asked to come on next Wednesday}

\item Video Conferencing with ADGQA
\myitem{13 Nov 2019--}{ pts for discussion}
\mysubitem{Padmavathy for Digital DGQA--}{She will be available for guidance but Kannan should take over \\ \llap{--}if required he can got to Bangalore}
\mysubitem{Component Level Repair CLR--}{  83 items\\ \llap{--}to be decided by CQAL, Bangalore\\Action by Debnath}
\mysubitem{FR 56j--}{  List upto Jun 2020 to be sent \\ \llap{--}list again faxed on 14 Nov 2019\\ Vishwanath case--decision already conveyed as told by Col Vibhor}
\mysubitem{Cover assembly BMP--}{  2017 pending?\\ FFT?\\ Delay to be pinpointed \\Delay in G1 Form? \\Action by Kambli}
\mysubitem{Digital DGQA--}{  Action by  --Kannan}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```